# Ruby bitcoind JSON RPCCall

Tags: bitcoind, client, ruby

I am trying the JSON-RPC call from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Ruby

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

class BitcoinRPC
  def initialize(service_url)
    @uri = URI.parse(service_url)
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    post_body = { 'method' => name, 'params' => args, 'id' => 'jsonrpc' }.to_json
    resp = JSON.parse( http_post_request(post_body) )
    raise JSONRPCError, resp['error'] if resp['error']
    resp['result']
  end

  def http_post_request(post_body)
    http    = Net::HTTP.new(@uri.host, @uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@uri.request_uri)
    request.basic_auth @uri.user, @uri.password
    request.content_type = 'application/json'
    request.body = post_body
    http.request(request).body
  end

  class JSONRPCError < RuntimeError; end
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  h = BitcoinRPC.new('http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:8332')
  p h.getbalance
  p h.getinfo
  p h.getnewaddress
  p h.dumpprivkey( h.getnewaddress )
end
```

But when I try running the file, I get a RPC.rb: end of file reached (EOFError)

I have the bitcoind running, I can run various commands, but I an not seem to get this script running.

Answer (score 1):

The code is free of syntax errors, but it looks like you need to replace the `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` in this line:

`h = BitcoinRPC.new('http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:8332')`

To the actual rpcuser and rpcpassword values that are set in your `bitcoin.conf` file.

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest doing some debugging by opening an `irb` session and running this code to see the result of the HTTP request to the RPC service:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

post_body = { method: 'getblockchaininfo', params: [], id: 'jsonrpc' }.to_json

uri = URI.parse "http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:8332"

def http_post_request(uri, post_body)
  http    = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  request.basic_auth uri.user, uri.password
  request.content_type = 'application/json'
  request.body = post_body
  http.request(request).body
end

http_post_request(uri, post_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know Ruby but these two lines looks off to me.

```
  class JSONRPCError < RuntimeError; end
end
```

Two `end`s?